# Extending classes when using autoload

Tags: php, oop, phpmailer, autoloader

I am using PHPMailer, and wish to extend the class so I may pre-set some values.  I have autoload set up so it so I don't need to require the file before evoking it. I don't want the actual settings to be located in `/var/www/classes/myPHPMailer.php` as I have two servers with different configuration so locate the settings in another file which Git ignores.  So, it looks something like the following.

Main File

```
<?php
function __autoload($class)
{
    if(file_exists('/var/www/classes/'.strtolower($class).'.php'))
        {require_once '/var/www/classes/'.strtolower($class).'.php';}
}

$mailer=new myPHPMailer(true);
//...
$mailer->send();
?>
```

Filename: /var/www/classes/myPHPMailer.php

```
<?php
require_once ('/var/www/private/email.php');
class myPHPMailer extends myPHPMailer_temp {}
?>
```

Filename: /var/www/private/email.php

```
<?php
require_once ('/var/www/other_classes/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
class myPHPMailer_temp extends PHPMailer {
    public function __construct($allow_exceptions=false){
        $this->isSMTP();
        $this->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $this->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $this->Port = 587;
        $this->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $this->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->Username = "Username@gmail.com";
        $this->Password = "Password";
    }
}
?>
```

I've been getting `Fatal error:  Class 'SMTP' not found in /var/www/other_classes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1173`

If I `require_once /var/www/private/email.php;` and directly evoke `myPHPMailer_temp`, I don't get the error.

How do I extend this class when using autoloader?  Also, how can I view what directories PHP will search in?  Before line 1173 (`$this->smtp = new SMTP;`), I wish to view the directories it is looking in so I could troubleshoot.

Thank you

Comment: You should perhaps consider using a consistent class naming convention. That's the strangest mix I've seen!

Comment: @Seer.  Please explain why it is strage.

Comment: It just seems like it's a mixture of styles, camel case, with underscores, and some things capitalised. I know this is in part PHPMailers fault, but I'd be calling it something like `TempPhpMailer` or something. Just to keep it consistent. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because the stock `PHPMailerAutoload.php` script assumes that the classes it's loading are in the same folder as itself.

Redefining `__autoload` isn't a good idea (unless you're on a very old PHP where you have no choice) as it will tend to break stuff that relies on what it was - the right way of adding your own class autoloader is to write an [SPL Autoloader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) and add it to the autoloader stack. This is what PHPMailer's autoloader does anyway, so you could follow that example.

In this case I'd recommend you copy the stock autoloader and alter it to point at your own class folder, which is more or less what @user1032531 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why replacing `function __autoload($class){...}` with this works, but it does.  I would appreciate any explanation that anyone could provide.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $class=strtolower($class);
    if(file_exists('/var/www/classes/'.$class.'.php'))
        {require_once '/var/www/classes'.DS.$class.'.php';}
});
```